# Ionic error: Unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I know this is a repeated question, but still I am posting the question as I unable to find the answer by all the method i check in the previous links. So, please help me instead of marking duplicate or voting down.

I have build an app with some cordova plugin including the push notification, but in some handsets its working good and in some its showing me as "Unfortunately appname has stopped" and the app is exits.

I have tried with some options like updating google play services, sdk update, adb logcat, keyboard uninstall and install, even platform also i have added again but no use.

Please save me from the bug.

Comment: Hey Nitin, you won't get help until you properly describe full context of your issue. There is no magic or guessing game here to try and help you. If you need help - provide full context of the issue and then ppl might help

Comment: @SergeyRudenko, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately I have found the solution.

The error was the `cordova-android@7.0.0` version.

I just updated my package from 7.0.0 to 7.1.0 and just re-installed all the plugins and its working pretty fine.

Now all the plugins even the push notifications are working good.

If anyone has the issue can just follow the same procedure and it will help you.

Comment: Great. Even I was having the same problem. Let me check with this solution.